# Are banks significantly reducing security by migrating everyone to mobile banking?

Tags: authentication, mobile, multi-factor, banks

I have noticed a disturbing trend across banks (in the EU). Previously, many banks used 2FA by combining a login/password for an online banking website with a mobile authenticator app. However, many banks now integrate the mobile authentication app with full-blown mobile banking, so there is no way to opt out of the latter. A single app on my phone thus became the only key to €10k+ of my money, which does not feel secure at all.

Depending on whether or not I enable biometric authentication, the whole app is protected either by a 4-8 digit PIN, or something like a fingerprint. Given that I need to frequently use the authentication part in all sorts of insecure situations to confirm random card purchases (e.g. buying a mobile ticket on public transport), any bystander can shoulder-surf the PIN (trivial for 4 digits, fairly simple with 6, not many people likely use 8). Then it's just a matter of grabbing the phone and transferring all my money out of my accounts before I notice. (With biometric auth enabled, if I happen to fall asleep on a train, anyone can brush the reader against my finger instead.)

Under the previous system, compromising the mobile authenticator was not a big concern, since it was only useful for card payments (which require the card/card data, are limited in amount and also strongly legally protected against fraud). The authenticator was useless for general banking without also knowing the online banking credentials, which people typically wouldn't expose in untrusted locations.

So why do banks consider this reduction in security acceptable? Am I just grossly misjudging the threat landscape and overestimating the risk associated with putting everything into a single mobile app, behind a single short PIN? Are there other factors mitigating the risks?

Comment: There's a famous clip of somebody with something like a 30+ digit pin, and people figured out what it was from analysis of the video.  That aside, anybody nabbing your phone is potentially more likely to be willing to engage in rubber-hose decryption techniques, so requiring a password would not likely be a significant security barrier.